# Docker registry - removing manifests from filesystem

Tags: docker, docker-registry

My CI pushes images to docker registry under one tag. I have a script that periodically cleans old unuser images. It just iterates over digests inside tag and calls DELETE on registry API (iterating over files on registry filesystem).

```
dir="${REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY}/docker/registry/v2/repositories/test/_manifests/tags/5.3/index/sha256/"
oldManifests=$(ls -t $dir | tail -n +2 ; done)
for hash in $oldManifests
do
    curl  -L -X DELETE http://localhost:5000/v2/test/manifests/sha256:$hash
done

/bin/registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

After garbage-collect all blobs are removed but not directories under _manifests/tags/5.3/index/sha256/ . Why? Is it safe to delete them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to delete them manually.

---

In your case the tag is versioned, it doesn't hurt to use `ls -t`.  In the case of "latest" tags it is better to check the content of the `.../_manifests/tags/5.3/current/link` (with `sha256:` prefix stripped) and proceed, because you may push an older manifest as a new "latest" when you downgrade a previously pushed image.

I have a script to purge untagged (your case) or tagged images from the Registry:
https://github.com/ricardobranco777/clean_registry.sh

I don't use the API because it lacks support to delete tags.

Comment: I have created a Python script and a Docker image available in the Docker Hub: https://github.com/ricardobranco777/clean_registry